# Adverbs to say "in another way"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, adverbs, transitions

Suppose we have this structure

> To do something, we can do this. **For another option**, we can do that too.

Which adverbs can be used in replace of **For another option**, or "in another way" (note these are my own terms)?

*Additionally*, *In addition* or *Also* doesn't seem to fit, because they would imply we can do this and in addition we can do the second (while we have done the first) (Or maybe I am wrong!?)

Comment: You might consider "**As** another option" as another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Alternatively' is a good choice or for something similar, just use 'or'.

You need to take off the  *too* as that implies you are doing both actions.

Comment: +1 though 'or else' might be slightly better at implying it's an either/or choice, not both.

Comment: There are also subtle differences depending upon if you are offering multiple ways of doing something, all equally good; or if you think that one option is your preferred choice but that there are other ways to achieve something.